# Mysql join producing huge result table for small solution set

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables where I'm trying to select rows where a common field between those tables matches exactly, however it's proving difficult to write the query. Here is a simplified version:

The tables look like this (simplified):

```
T1:
  id, name, sn

T2:
  id, location, sn
```

I'm trying to get t1.name and t2.loc together only where t1.sn=t2.sn. The sn field is unique in both, and so at the most, only 1 record will match between tables. In t1, all records have a sn field value, however in t2 about 30% of them have NULL for sn. So, I an expecting the join to produce somewhat fewer rows than t1 has.

How would I do the join?

Thanks.

Sample data:

```
t1:
+---+--------+-------+-----+
| id| name   | sn    | ... |
+---+--------+-------+-----+
| 1 | thing1 | 12345 |     |
| 2 | thing2 | 10000 |     |
| 3 | thing3 | 33445 |     |
| 4 | thing4 | 99223 |     |
+---+--------+-------+-----+

T2:
+----+--------+-------+-----+
| id | loc    | sn    | ... |
+----+--------+-------+-----+
| 90 | here   | 12345 |     |
| 92 | there  | NULL  |     |
| 96 | near   | 33445 |     |
| 99 | far    | 99223 |     |
+----+--------+-------+-----+

Result:
+--------+-------+-------+
| name   | loc   | sn    |
+--------+-------+-------+
| thing1 | here  | 12345 |
| thing3 | near  | 33445 |
| thing4 | far   | 99223 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: In this example above, something akin to: "select name, loc, t1.sn from t1 join t2 on t1.sn=t2.sn". The thinking being the query would return rows where the sn values matched. My actual DB has 30k rows in it, and when I set it running and wait, the results table has about 400k rows before I finally kill off the query.

Comment: try this to verify your unicity of t2.sn: select t1.id, count(1) as nb from t1 inner join t2 on (t1.sn=t2.sn) group by t1.id having nb>1

Comment: @MikeC: But are the 400k results you're obtaining incorrect?  Is your question really about how to improve the performance of that query (to which my first answer would be ensure that you have indexes in both tables on their respective `sn` columns)?

Comment: @Keil: when I run this on the production DB, I end up with this: id: 51, nb: 1403, id: 360, nb: 1403, id: 477, nb: 1403...  So something does not seem right. :/

Comment: @eggyal: No, they're not the results I'm expecting at all. Many columns show up multiple times (probably 1,403 times, as the above comment seems to suggest).

Comment: Please can edit your question to include the outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE t1` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE t2`?

Comment: i haven't tried, but i doubt mysql will let you unique-index a can-be-null field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.name AS name,
  t2.loc AS loc,
  t1.sn AS sn
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.sn=t2.sn
```

Comment: @which makes it clear, that the structure of your production DB and the structure of the sample are different: a query with only `INNER JOIN`s can never give more records, than the smallest joined table (provided the joinfields are unque)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eugen. That explains a lot, and looking back at the data I was provided I found that the initial premise was not correct. There are duplicate sn's in t2, which is causing the returned values to be beyond the expectation were they unique. Thanks all for your contributions.